# Project Euler Number 8 Python

Tags: python

So the question asks to find the largest product of thirteen consecutive integers in a massive integer. I have looked through some of the other solutions on SO and none of them work quite the same way as my proposed solution.

```
from numpy import product
def function():
    x=#massive integer goes here, x is a string which I then turn into a list.
    my_list=[]
    for i in x:
        my_list.append(int(i))
    j=0
    while j+12 < len(my_list):
        answer=long(0)
        my_slice=my_list[j:(j+12)]
        test=long(product(my_slice))
        if test>answer:
            answer=test
            j+=1
        else:
            j+=1
        return answer
```

This piece of code returns 1666980L which is orders of magnitude too small but i can not see my mistake.

Comment: You've indented your `return answer` so it's inside the `while` loop. This means you try the first 13 numbers, get `1666980L`, and then just `return` that without trying anything else.

Comment: Also, assuming neither index is negative or out of bounds, `lst[a:b]` will always have `b-a` elements (because `lst[b]` is excluded).  `my_list[j:j+12]` is thus one element too short.

Comment: A few side notes on this code: If you're not using an ancient (2.3? I forget…) version of Python, don't use `long(…)` all over place; just use `int` and it'll overflow to `long` automatically as needed. If you _are_ using an ancient version, your code is wrong; by the time the `product` has been truncated or whatever, it's too late to convert it to `long`; you need to store `long` values in the list in the first place, at which point the `long(…)` conversions become unnecessary again.

Comment: Also, using numpy to make arrays out of slices of a giant list is getting the worst of both worlds. Either create a giant numpy array in the first place and slice _that_, or leave numpy out of it and just write a 1-liner `product` function on lists.

Comment: currently using 2.7, i though that the behaviour of int was changed for 3.x python? could you explain exactly what you mean by the second part of the comment? @abarnert

Comment: The behavior of `int` and `long` was changed twice. Somewhere around 2.4, they were "mostly unified", so that you can mix `int` and `long` freely, and even when you use two `int` values, if the result is too big for an `int`, you get a `long`. Then, in 3.0, `int` was removed and `long` was renamed to `int`.

Comment: For the second half of that comment: `long(product(my_slice))` first calls `product` with a bunch of `int` values, then it gets back an `int` or `long`, then it converts that to `long`. That's too late to avoid overflow in the `product` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are least two problems here.

First, as [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) pointed out in a comment, you've indented your return answer so it's inside the while loop. This means you try the first batch of numbers, get 1666980L, and then just return that without trying anything else.

Second, as [jwodder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744178/jwodder) pointed out in a comment, `[j:j+12]` is a slice of 12 numbers, not 13. Slices, ranges, etc. in Python are all half-open, meaning they include everything from the start, up to but not including the end. So, you need `[j:j+13]`.

Comment: Since people insist on answering this question instead of closing it, I've created a community-wiki answer, referencing the two comments that identified the problems 2 hours previous, allowing the asker to fix his code before any of the answers were even posted.

Answer (score -1):

your slice isn't 13 long python slice notation is [m:n), the last index is excluded, so you for need to account this by adding one to your slice i.e.

`my_slice=my_list[j:(j+12)]`